# Subquery Inside Mega Query

Tags: oracle

I have searched, but can find no example that fits what I need. Perhaps I am lost in the many joins of my query...

I am returning data from three Oracle 11g tables - ATE_TESTS, ATE_DATA, and TM_CONDITION_DYNAMIC. The query has other tables to join these. In fact, there are no less than 7 Joins.

ATE_DATA may have multiple records on the Many side of a join, but I want only the last-written row. ATE_DATA has an incremented Primary Key which I would like to use in the Aggregate Function MAX(DATA_PK) within a subquery. I think it should be in the WHERE clause of the main query, but I do not know how to implement this and there may be a better way.

Perhaps I might be educated?

My query is:

```
SELECT ate_serial, data_data, dyn_value
FROM   ate_tests
       LEFT JOIN ate_test_procedure
         ON ate_tests.ate_pk = ate_test_procedure.proc_ate_test_fk
       LEFT JOIN ate_test_data
         ON ate_test_procedure.proc_pk = ate_test_data.data_ate_test_procedure_fk
       LEFT JOIN tm_test_procedure
         ON ate_test_procedure.proc_test_procedure = tm_test_procedure.proc_pk
       LEFT JOIN tm_test_specification
         ON ate_test_data.data_specification = tm_test_specification.spec_pk
       LEFT JOIN tm_test_condition_dynamic
         ON tm_test_specification.spec_condition_set_fk = tm_test_condition_dynamic.dyn_condition_set_fk
       LEFT JOIN tm_test_sequences
         ON ate_tests.ate_sequence_fk = tm_test_sequences.seq_pk
       LEFT JOIN lu_tm_products_model
         ON tm_test_sequences.seq_model = lu_tm_products_model.lumod_pk
WHERE  upper(spec_name) = 'POWER'
AND    lumod_model = 'AMP'
AND    dyn_value = '136'
AND    ate_yield = 1
AND    upper(proc_procedure_name) = 'FINAL TEST'
AND    proc_report = 1
AND    proc_status = 1
ORDER BY ate_serial, dyn_value
```

Comment: As it stands, we know nothing about your tables, your data nor exactly what you want the query to do. Please try and produce a simple test case that is enough to demonstrate what you want to achieve (surely only 2 or 3 joins are needed to demonstrate your scenario?) along with the corresponding input and expected output data.

Comment: Thank you, Boneist. I will post a scaled-down query with an example.

Comment: Based on the posted query, should we assume that the table you refer to as `ATE_DATA` in the question is actually `ATE_TEST_DATA`, and that `TM_CONDITION_DYNAMIC` is actually `TM_TEST_CONDITION_DYNAMIC`? If so, please correct the table names mentioned in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Bob. That is true.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I want only the last-written row.

It's typical top-n query. Let's say table `a` contains info about vegetables, table `b` their historical prices in different shops and `s` info about these shops. You are interested only in last price, 
which you can find using the function `row_number()` (or `max() ... keep dense rank last...`).

```
with a as (select 1 vid, 'Tomato' name from dual union all
           select 2 vid, 'Potato' name from dual union all
           select 3 vid, 'Garlic' name from dual),

     b as (select 1 pid, 1 vid, 1 sid, 11.5 price from dual union all 
           select 2 pid, 3 vid, 1 sid, 31.8 price from dual union all
           select 3 pid, 1 vid, 1 sid, 13.2 price from dual union all
           select 4 pid, 1 vid, 2 sid, 12.7 price from dual ),

     s as (select 1 sid, 'Best Vegetables'  name from dual union all
           select 2 sid, 'Organic Products' name from dual)

select a.vid, a.name, s.name as shop, p.price as last_price
  from a 
    left join (select vid, sid, price 
                 from (select vid, sid, price, 
                              row_number() over (partition by vid order by pid desc) rn 
                         from b)
                 where rn = 1) p
      on p.vid = a.vid
    left join s on s.sid = p.sid
  order by a.vid
```

Output:

```
VID  Name      Shop                Price
---  --------  ------------------  -------
  1  Tomato    Organic Products       12.7
  2  Potato
  3  Garlic    Best Vegetables        31.8
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am truly lost now. I am sure this is a solution, but it escapes me what it is doing and how I implement it into my SQL.